# Stream a Iterator vs forEachRemaining

Tags: java, java-8, iterator, java-stream

I have a Iterator and I need to pass that to an Array, I can do dat with a forEachRemaining.

```
List<Page> array = new ArrayList<>();
iterator.forEachRemaining(array::add);
```

In otherside I can do that with a Stream

```
array = StreamSupport.stream(
              Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
                      iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED),
              false).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

So my question is which one is better? I mean if one is has better performance than another.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It almost certainly doesn't matter. Do the one which is clearest to understand. I would refuse to believe that the latter is clearer than the former.

Comment: The first version definitely run faster. As you don't have overhead of Stream or Spliterators. It's pretty straightforward

Comment: The first variant creates an `ArrayList` and fills it via repeated `add` calls. The second just declares that you want a `List` containing all elements, letting the framework decide how to do it. The result will be the same, even what happens technically (in the current implementation) will be the same, but it has different semantics. Which is better? Depends on which semantic you prefer.

Comment: choose the first one, it is *at least* way more readable.

Comment: Note: An `ArrayList` is not an array, it is a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect the first approach to perform better as there is less work to be performed as opposed to the second approach which involves several method calls internally and and all other sorts of stuff.

For example, the `forEachRemaining` is defined as;

```
default void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
     Objects.requireNonNull(action);
     while (hasNext())
         action.accept(next());
}
```

On the other hand, a call to `stream(Spliterator<T> spliterator, boolean parallel)` leads to more work being done internally which will have an effect on the performance.

That said, the first approach is definitely more readable. As for the exact statistics of both approaches, you'll need to measure.

Comment: The most performance relevant work is the bulk processing in case of a large number of elements, in other words, the loop in case of the `default` implementation of `forEachRemaining` shown in your answer. And…well, guess where the Stream variant will end up after going through the initial overhead. The consumer will differ slightly, but in either case, represent calling `add` on the target `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Aominè as Brian once said, we are in the process of reading code a lot more than writing code, I would go with the first one for this reason

Comment: @Eugene Agreed, just as hinted/mentioned in my answer ;-). obviously, not word for word...